# How to see what locales a given Node.js version supports and how to enable missing locales?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localization, ecmascript-intl

My Node.js version on Windows 8.1 is:

```
$ node -v
v5.3.0
```

But it seems it doesn't support locale identification and negotiation. I mean the support of [ECMAScript Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl). Only `en` locale is supported. Here is an example in a browser and in Node.js. In a browser a locale is identified just fine:

```
// en
> Intl.NumberFormat('en', {currency: 'USD', style:"currency"}).format(300)
> "$300.00"

// ru
> Intl.NumberFormat('ru', {currency: 'USD', style:"currency"}).format(300)
> "300,00 $"
```

But in Node.js it doesn't work. Node.js returns the same `en` format for both `en` and `ru`:

```
// en
> Intl.NumberFormat('en', {currency: 'USD', style:"currency"}).format(300)
'$300.00'

// ru
> Intl.NumberFormat('ru', {currency: 'USD', style:"currency"}).format(300)
'$300.00'
```

Is there a way to see what locales does a given Node.js support and how can I enable desired locales?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15223

Answer (score 3):

Hy,

According to https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/ there is a nodejs module, called

> intl-locales-supported

which shows if a locale is supported.

```js
var areIntlLocalesSupported = require('intl-locales-supported');

var localesMyAppSupports = [
    /* list locales here */
];

if (global.Intl) {
    // Determine if the built-in `Intl` has the locale data we need.
    if (!areIntlLocalesSupported(localesMyAppSupports)) {
        // `Intl` exists, but it doesn't have the data we need, so load the
        // polyfill and patch the constructors we need with the polyfill's.
        var IntlPolyfill    = require('intl');
        Intl.NumberFormat   = IntlPolyfill.NumberFormat;
        Intl.DateTimeFormat = IntlPolyfill.DateTimeFormat;
    }
} else {
    // No `Intl`, so use and load the polyfill.
    global.Intl = require('intl');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to support *different* locales for *different* subsets of the `Intl` API, so ECMA-402 doesn't expose APIs that answer whether a locale is "supported".  Rather, it exposes APIs for *each* particular form of behavior, to indicate whether a locale is supported *for that form*.  So if you want to ask whether a locale is supported, you'll have to separately query for each `Intl` subset you're going to use.

To query `Intl.NumberFormat` for support of a locale, use the `Intl.NumberFormat.supportedLocalesOf` function:

```
function isSupportedForNumberFormatting(locale)
{
  return Intl.NumberFormat.supportedLocalesOf([locale]).length > 0;
}
```

Assuming Node properly supports this, `isSupportedForNumberFormatting("ru")` would return `false`, while `isSupportedForNumberFormatting("en")` would return `true`.

Similar code should work for `Intl.Collator` and `Intl.DateTimeFormat` if you swap in the appropriate constructor name.  And if you're using existing ECMA-262 functions that are locale-sensitive, like `NumberFormat.prototype.toLocaleString`, that ECMA-402 reformulates in terms of `Intl` primitives, check for support on the relevant `Intl` constructor (in that case, `Intl.NumberFormat`).

Comment: It was also be nice if you could obtain a list of supported locales and [supported currencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58029344/).

Comment: Given how infrequently currencies change, and that currencies are identified by code and the code itself is always an available fallback display form, of rough intelligibility to a fair number of users, the current spec behavior of "we'll give you something for any identified currency" is not too terrible.  IMO.  I added a comment to this effect to your link.

The spec could be changed to add a testing mechanism, if there were enough demand.  But I don't remember seeing anyone else express the concern in the past.

Comment: Currencies are not the only thing that I've run across like this. [Time-zones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54500197/217867) are another example. Instead of just being able to ask the environment, "What timezones do your support?", you have to acquire them from a source that's outside of the environment itself. And, if you don't think timezones change much [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459791/why-so-many-iana-time-zones-names). The spec writers could do a better job on providing reflective interfaces for acquiring things from the environment instead of outside sources.